# Spark watermark taking too much time for doing group by operation?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I tried to doing some groupby operation throw spark structured streaming, it was giving the output as expected, But my problem is it was taking more than 10 mins but my watermark time is "30 seconds" only, below  code i tried

```java
Dataset<Row> windowedCounts = lines
    .withWatermark("timestamp", "30 seconds")
    .groupBy("value")
    .count();
```

And i tried window operations like below mentioned

```java
Dataset<Row>windowedCounts = lines
    .withWatermark("timestamp", "30 seconds")
    .groupBy(
        functions.window(lines.col("timestamp"), "30 seconds", "10 seconds"),
        lines.col("value"))
    .count();
```

And i analysed in UI there was 200 task was there, i don't know why it was creating 200 task for this calculation?Any help will be appreciate Thank in advance..!

Answer (score 1):

> And i analysed in UI there was 200 task was there, i don't know why it was creating 200 task for this calculation?

200 tasks is the default number of tasks after `groupBy`. Nothing unusual.

> But my problem is it was taking more than 10 mins but my watermark time is "30 seconds" only

The current value of event-time watermark depends on the values in the event rows. It is possible that the events didn't move the watermark only until 10 mins passed by when an event with the `timestamp` value that moved the threshold.

In order to debug the issue (if there's any), you should monitor `timestamp` values of event rows and the logs of the Spark app as the current watermark threshold is printed out to logs every batch.

Comment: Can you please guide me  programmatically

Comment: Let's start by looking at the events. Can you include some events so I can make my answer more correct and to the point? Without real events I'm almost guessing.

Comment: timestamp = 2019-11-25 06:33.20 ,  value = California

Comment: kafka timestamp field values as a timestamp

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add many events so I can explain how watermark works?